# Format number with leading zeros and thousand separator

Tags: c#, formatting, tostring

I'd like to format an integer in a way that it has leading zeros **and** thousand separators at the same time.

I know that `someInt.ToString("D6");` will give me leading zeros, but apparently it doesn't allow `NumberGroupSeparator`. On the other hand `someInt.ToString("N");` will give me separators but no leading zeros...

Is it possible to combine both to print `123456` as `00 123 456`? I know I can get string created with `N` and then manually add zeros to string in a loop or something, but maybe there's better way?

EDIT:
Number of padding zeros (total digits length of number) should be adjustable.

Comment: Why would it be "00123 456" rather than "00 123 456"? And is space really your thousands separator?

Comment: Thanks, my mistake, I corrected it. It will be space or apostrophe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 00 123 456, just do:

```
123456.ToString("00 000 000")
```

If you need a fixed amount of zero's, all I can think of is this:

```
int NUM_LENGTH = 6;

//This is not very elegant
var NUM_STR = String.Join("", Enumerable.Range(0, NUM_LENGTH).Select((x, i) => (NUM_LENGTH - i) % 3 == 0 ? " 0" : "0"));

//But at least it works:
var example1 = 123456.ToString(NUM_STR); //Outputs  123 456
var example2 = 1234.ToString(NUM_STR); //Outputs 001 234
```

Comment: I edited my question. I need number length to be adjustable. The formatting is for meter display image.

Comment: You mean you need as many zeros as the length of the number? Otherwise you can do 12.ToString("00 000 000") or 123456.ToString("0 000") for example.

Comment: I mean that I'd like to be able to set this length from a variable. This is closed control with a parameter that sets length of number (actual length of number doesn't matter). Normally I did it with `12345.ToString("D" + NUM_LENGTH);` where `NUM_LENGTH` was this variable. Now I need thousand separators too...

Comment: See my update. I can't think any other way of doing it unfortunately.

Comment: I get a feeling there must be a better way to achieve what you want.

Comment: Actually, forget that. I think I know how to do it. One moment.

Comment: Nope. I was hoping I could combine it with 123456.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("se-SE")) somehow but that still doesn't work. This was quite a good question. :)

Comment: You're missing `.ToArray()` at the end but otherwise it's working well. I made also a small change to be able to set other separator with `NumberFormatInfo`.

Comment: Hmmm... Worked without toarray for me. (Made a small correction to the NUM_STR function).

Answer (score 2):

I think the following should work.

```
int value = 102145;
int num_length = 10; // it may change as you expected
string format = "000,000,000,000,000";
string tmp = value.ToString(format);
Console.Out.WriteLine(tmp.Substring(tmp.Length - num_length - tmp.Length/4 + 1 ));
```

Please let me know whether it works or not.

**Corrected & working version:**

```
int value = 102145;
int num_length = 12;
string format = "000,000,000,000,000,000";
string tmp = value.ToString(format);
int totalLength = format.Replace("000,", "000").Length;
int rem = (totalLength - num_length ) / 3;
Console.Out.WriteLine(tmp.Substring(totalLength - num_length + rem));
```

Comment: It prints 9 digits when I set num_length to 8, but otherwise it works. +1 from me but I'm waiting for more answers :).

Comment: ohh, I see. The formulla is not correct. I am working on this. Thanks

Comment: Please see the updated code. It works for any length. Please mark it also as an answer if it's okay with your purpose. Thanks

Comment: Since the code is a bit lengthy, you can write a common extension method so that it works like a single line function, i hope.

Comment: Thanks for update! Indeed this code works well now. I accepted the answer that I actually used. Mostly because it returns format string, so it leaves me freedom to choose separator through `NumberFormatInfo`. I gave you +1 for this answer as it is correct too. As far as I know it's not possible to mark two answers as Answer on SO though.

Comment: Thanks @Episodex. I am new to SO. So, i thought it's possible to mark two answer as Answer. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
 .toString("#,###");
```

Comment: You guys want to take another shot at writing code that compiles? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to use the Standard format strings to acheive what you're after, however you're going to need to look at the [Custom Numeric Format Strings (MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx). These should enable to set things up exactly as you require.