# Combining an int value starting with 0000 with another int value

Tags: c#

```
int myNeedNumber;
int userCodeTest = 0000;
int userNumber = 3;
```

what i need is to concatenate two int values to get an int value. But since the number starts with 0, I can only get the value 3.
i need is to get the number 00003.

Comment: It sound like you need strings, not integers

Comment: have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9989826/format-number-with-leading-zeros-and-thousand-separator

Answer (score 0):

I think you need use `PadLeft` method on `string` type variable. Every `int` type will trim leading zeroes and number will be always ”3”.

Code appropriate for your needs:

```
string myNeedNumber = userNumber.ToString().PadLeft(5, '0')
```

It will take your number and fill with leading zeroes that all characters in `string` equal 5.

Answer (score 0):

Numeric types won't allow left zeros.
You need to use string.

There several ways of how to do it.

try:

```
var numberFormatted = userNumber.ToString("00000");
```